# Classic keyboard/mouse input "converted" into android touch input

Tags: java, android, input, keyboard, mouse

For some time I was working on a java project - simple game where you have to dodge different objects, pick up healthpacks and so on. I had no problems with keyboard / mouse input. However, I decided to remake the game so it will work on android phones, but I have no idea what to do with the input? Is there a tutorial which would show me what to do?

What else do I have to be careful about? What to do with the resolution and Jframe window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `onTouch()` to input commands, you could set up the screen so that if you are touching closest to the top the guy will move up, closest to the right the guy will move down and so on...

You should look on Google as there should be plenty of tutorials on this like this one.[this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-basic-game.html)

Comment: thank you, yeah I figured out it's probably the best to learn android from the start, and remake the code after.